colon(:) considered As a dot (.) when its going to set in textview android
I have some string that are coming from API response.
when I trying to set that string to android TextView it will convert : (colon) character to . (dot) character.
Name : Learning Always shows As
Name . Learning Always
I have used simple textview with below attributes
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_body"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        tools:text="Title" />

Update
Please find code snippet from app where using simple text view to show title
App Image :

Code :


Check twice if it is colon (not fx ratio) sign.

I have Updated question with snippet

Again, check char value not string
